# Printing HTTPS Webpages in CLI

Tags: centos, printing, cups, lpr

I have a CentOS 6.6 server, and I am trying to print https://* webpages using the following commands:

```
html2ps https://mywebsite/blah.html | lpr
```

My printer prints out a paper for all HTTPS print jobs, but only prints out "IB" in the top right. Very strange. Is it possible to print https web pages using these commands??

Printing http://* pages and local files work just fine.

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: Maybe `curl https://mywebsite/blah.html | html2ps | lpr`?

Comment: That worked!!! I just added the -k flag and all set!